# Comma values in tab & delimited files for Orange

Tags: python, orange

For a first playing around, I just tried to import some data into orange and came across the problem, that if my CSV contains data like: "0,5m rope" or anything else with a , Orange can't handle the import.
[Orange Python data load error: "example of invalid length"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973580/orange-python-data-load-error-example-of-invalid-length)
Problem is, that the comma values are important in my data and I can't really change them into anything else.

Can I work around this issue somehow without changing my data?

Comment: If __all__ your data is in this format `(number),(number)m` (e.g `0,5m` or `1,2m`) you could first parse the file (using `regex`) to change the __comma__ for a __dot__ making it e.g `0.5m`and `1.2m`. Then just read the CSV normally

Comment: you can open your csv file in excel and change the "delimiters" property to anything else than "," like ";"

Comment: I can't do either unfortunately.
Some data values contain "word, word" other contain "number, number" - and the "word, word" is important for the logic (I could still convert the number, number - but not the word, word)

I tried different delimiter like tab, semicolon and comma - but neither of those versions worked. I even tried it with different text separator like " and ' but only if I get rid of all , within my data orange can correctly import data.

Comment: try "#" or "@" or "&" or "|"

Comment: Same problem - I don't think the delimiter is the problem but Orange with the import of commas inside values!?

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote this parser, but it was more than 10 years ago, so I just checked it again. I don't see any way to escape commas in csv files. Sorry about that. We always preferred tab-delimited formats. Orange 3 will be smarter.

Rename the file to .txt and use tabulator as delimiter.

```
name    gender  height  comment
John    male    1,83    None
Jane    female  1.54    Likes commas, uses .txt format
```

@Rafael: By the way, Orange actually accepts both , and . in numbers, like in the example above.

**Edit**: Sorry, I knew we had it somewhere. There's another parser. If you use canvas, go to Preferences / Categories and enable Prototypes. A new widget category with a lot of (abandonded) experimental stuff will appear. There, choose CSV File import and configure it appropriately. Commas are "escaped" like here:

```
name,gender,comment
John,m,None
Jane,f,"Likes commas, but no problems with that"
```

Comment: Cool .. seemed to be fine first - but the problem is now, it can't handle UTF-8 - even though the commas are handled correct now.